# Insert a png image in a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, png

I'm trying to insert a png image in matplotlib figure ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639369/does-adding-images-in-pyplot-lowers-their-resolution/48643217#48643217))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox


ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )
arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.png")
im = OffsetImage(arr_img)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
```

Inset image:

[image]

Output obtained:

[image]

I'd like to know how to resize the image that has to be inserted to avoid overlaps.

EDIT:
Saving the figure

```
ax.figure.savefig("output.svg", transparent=True, dpi=600, bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can zoom the image and the set the box alignment to the lower right corner (0,1) plus some extra for the margins:

```
im = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=.45)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', box_alignment=(1.1,-0.1))
```

[image]

You may also want to use data coordinates, which is the default, and use the default box_alignment to the center, e.g. `ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (2.6, 1.45))`. See the [xycoords parameter doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation) for more information about various coordinate options.

Comment: Hi @Stef When I try to save this file `fig.savefig("output.svg", transparent=True, dpi=600, bbox_inches="tight")`, unfortunately I am not abele to find the inset in the output image

Comment: `savefig` works for me correctly ( matplotlib version 3.3.1). What version are you using?

Comment: hm, all I can say is that it works for me without any problems, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtUKI.png, using exactly the command you gave in your comment or edit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the version last time. I'm using matplotlib 3.3.3

Comment: [here](https://file.io/tJVMtVi0h4sE) is my output.svg as shown in the browser in the previous comment, does it look correctly when you open it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the image. I see the same problem when I download and open the image in the Pycharm window. When I open it in a browser it works without any problem.