# Does Matplotlib have figures that can be plotted?

Tags: python, forms, matplotlib, figure

I'm generating orbit plots and I would like to know if Matplotlib has any function that can generate figures. The idea would be to represent on the graph the point where the orbit is being captured. So, it would be nice to be able to plot a telescope or an eye at a specific point on the graph, something like that. Can Matplotlib do that? Below I provide an example of what I want more or less. In the image, I generated the graph, but I drew the eye by hand in Word. Is it possible to generate it with Python?

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eN8b.png)

Comment: Never done it before, but I am pretty sure you can do with adding new axes to your figures (give them the location of your image icon) and then call imshow on these new axes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a small image on the corner of a plot with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609585/how-to-insert-a-small-image-on-the-corner-of-a-plot-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65387500/12131013